# DataTable serverSide export

Tags: datatables

I am using DataTable with serverSide processing, there is a menu to export the data but it will only export the data that was loaded. Is there a setting in the buttons section to get all the data without using the page limiting the export? So if the page load page 1 with 50 records and there are three other pages with 50 records the export will all 150 rows of data? I did try this `https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/59216/customizing-the-data-from-export-buttons#latest` but its not working. The GetDataToExport is never called there are not errors. I have included the html because I am not sure if its getting bypass.

```
  buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'print',
                title: $(actions).closest("div").find(".caption").text(),
                exportOptions: {
                    orthogonal: 'export',
                    columns: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdf',
                orientation: 'landscape',
                title: $(actions).closest("div").find(".caption").text(),
                exportOptions: {
                    orthogonal: 'export',
                    columns: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'csv',
                title: $(actions).closest("div").find(".caption").text(),
                exportOptions: {
                    orthogonal: 'export',
                    columns: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                    customizeData: function (d) {
                        var exportBody = GetDataToExport();
                        console.log('exportBody');
                        d.body.length = 0;
                        d.body.push.apply(d.body, exportBody);
                    }
                }
            }
        ]


function GetDataToExport() {
    console.log('Not Getting Called');
    var jsonResult = $.ajax({
        url: 'GetPermissions.ashx?page=all',
        data: { search: $("#search").val() },
        success: function (result) { },
        async: false
    });
    var exportBody = jsonResult.responseJSON.data;
    return exportBody.map(function (el) {
        return Object.keys(el).map(function (key) { return el[key] });
    });
}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="btn-group">
                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="javascript:;" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <i class="fa fa-share"></i>
                            <span class="hidden-xs">Export </span>
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right permissions_tools" id="permissions_tools">
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:;" data-action="0" class="tool-action">
                                    <i class="icon-printer"></i>Print
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:;" data-action="1" class="tool-action">
                                    <i class="icon-doc"></i>PDF
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:;" data-action="2" class="tool-action">
                                    <i class="icon-cloud-upload"></i>CSV
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

updated

```
                        <li>
                            <a id="exportAllData" data-action="3" class="tool-action">
                                <i class="icon-cloud-upload"></i>ALL CSV
                            </a>
                        </li>
```

Comment: "_it will only export the data that was loaded_" - Yes, that is how Button-related exports work in DataTables. They therefore do not combine well with server-side processing, where the goal is to send as little data as necessary to the browser. Server-side processing is typically only used when you have too many records (hundreds of thousands? millions?) to send to the browser all at once. If you _need_ server-side processing, then you also _probably_ need server-side data exports (not DataTables exports).

Comment: (But if you only have 150 records, then you do not need server-side processing at all, I would argue.)

Comment: Sorry I was just using 150 records to make my question easier to understand

Comment: @andrewJames in this customizeData is there a setting to change it to ALL

Comment: No problem - my general point remains the same. If you _do_ need server-side processing due to large data volumes (large enough to make downloading and/or rendering unacceptably slow), then I would suggest using a server-side export approach. If you really do want a custom browser-based "download it all just for exporting" option, you can show us how you have implemented that (e.g. where is your `GetDataToExport()` code?), and help clarify what "its not working" means, more specifically. Any errors? Does your server side API have a "send all data" handler?

Comment: (no - there is no "get it all" setting, because Buttons exports assume "all" the data is already available in the underlying DataTable. But that is what the `GetDataToExport()` function does - it works around that assumption, if you provide the code to support it.)

Comment: so that GetDataToExport function is not getting called when I try to export the data.

Comment: Understood - Thank you. You can add that clarification to the question, since it is directly relevant to the problem you are having. Any errors thrown in the browser console?

Comment: I cannot recreate your problem. The function `GetDataToExport()` is called correctly, when I use your code. My `GetDataToExport()` doesn't do anything except contain a console logging statement. But it is called. You need to provide a [mre], I think.

Comment: are you using the same HTML code? with the javascript:;

Comment: The HTML code in your question? Yes - but that code does not appear to do anything useful. I click on the `CSV` button created by your DataTables code. And I ignore the links created by your HTML code.

Comment: Maybe you are looking to create [custom buttons](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/custom) to replace the standard ones generated automatically by DataTables?

Comment: @andrewJames I have been able to get call `GetDataToExport` but I am not sure how to create the file. Can I call dt to build this file?

Comment: You don't "call dt" to create the file. The code you have does this for you already. The `customizeData` function takes the data returned by your `GetDataToExport` function and creates the file from that data. Of course, your `GetDataToExport` therefore needs to provide the right data in the right format for this to work. So... what data is returned from your "get all data" endpoint? What does the URL `GetPermissions.ashx?page=all` return? It should return a JSON structure like `"data": [ ... ]`, where the array contains your entire data set (one JSON object per row).

Comment: Yes it returns a dataset but I had to create a new button with a click event

Comment: Use the DataTables CSV export button. Create a [customized DataTables button](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/custom) if you don't want (or cannot use) their default CSV export button.